# How to update MySQL text column with concat with a prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, prepared-statement, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate a text column with `UPDATE` in my database but I am unable to find any resouces online that explain how to do with a prepared statement. I keep getting an error:

> syntax to use near '(admin_notes=?) WHERE id=?' at line 1

```
UPDATE problem_report SET concat(admin_notes=?) WHERE id=?
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to UPDATE the admin_notes column. You need to concat the value not the column itself.

```
UPDATE problem_report SET admin_notes = concat(admin_notes,?) WHERE id=?
```